# Matplotlib - Plot does not show after plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When trying to plot something using matplotlib, the plot is shown immediately after running `plt.plot()`, but not after `plt.show()`. Any changes that were done after `plt.plot()`, such as added axis labels, also do not show. I tried to run the code in Atom and Rodeo, both did not work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
year = [1950, 1970, 1990, 2010]
pop = [2.519, 3.692, 5.263, 6.972]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(year,pop) 
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Population")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Because `plt.show()` comes directly after `plt.plot()` you cannot even see the difference which command actually triggered the figure to appear. Unless the code you show is not the code you are talking about (which would make little sense) or you did something other than running that code in completeness (which would require the question to tell what that would be).

Comment: Can you edit the question to represent the code when you added axis labels?

Comment: I ran it line by line, that's how I knew when the plot appeared. I also played around with adding axix labels, so I'll edit the question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Is your query resolved?

Comment: Well, if you run it line by line, then you should ask about running it line by line. If `plot` is in its own cell, it will produce the plot as output. In a new cell, `plt.show()` would not even know what to show, because there is nothing to be shown given that it is the only thing in that cell.

Comment: @anna Which backend? Your code works for me with `tkagg`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code both `plot()` and `show()` happen instantaneously. Yet `show()` works only after `plot()`. To test this out use the `sleep()` method to confirm.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
year = [1950, 1970, 1990, 2010]
pop = [2.519, 3.692, 5.263, 6.972]
plt.figure()
plt.plot(year,pop)
sleep(5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Using `sleep` doen't seem to make a difference in my code. When I run one line after the other, the plot still appears when I run the `plt.plot()` line instead of only appearing after `plt.show()`.

Comment: If you remove plt.show(), does the plot still appear?

Comment: Yes,it still appears.